# Get a loop to run based on amount of seconds

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting the loop to run on seconds `int n =  1580;//number of moves;` should be the number of seconds but the output I get for seconds is different.

I am also having trouble getting the X and Y co-ordinates to be correct sometimes the co-ordinates are correct sometimes not.

```
public class Steps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  forward1, left1;
    forward1 = left1 = 1;
    
    int forward2, left2, back, right;
    left2 = back = 0;
    forward2 = right = 1;
    //counts for X coordinate
    int countLeft = 0;//count moves left moves
    int countRight = 0;//count moves right moves
    
    //counts for Y coordinate
    int countForward = 0;//count moves forward moves
    int countBack = 0;//count moves right moves
    
    int n =  11;//number of moves;
    int i = 1;//iterator
    int all = 0;//count total seconds
    
    for(i=1; i<n;i++) {//the algorithm focuses on steps and not seconds.
        if(i<n) {
            System.out.println("Forward " + forward1);
            left2 += 1;
            i+=1;
            all++;
            //System.out.println(countForward);
            
            
            if(i<n) {
                for(int j = 0; j < left2; j++) {
                    System.out.println("left: " + left2);
                    countLeft++;
                    all++;//count seconds
                }
                back += 1;
                i+=1;
                
                
                //System.out.println(countLeft);
                
                if(i<n) {
                    for(int j=0;j<back;j++) {
                        System.out.println("back: " + back);
                        countBack++;
                        all++;
                        //System.out.println(countBack);
                    }
                    
                    left2 += 1;
                    i+=1;
                    back += 1;
                    
         
                    
                    if(i<n) {
                        System.out.println("left: "+left1);
                        forward2++;
                        i+=1;
                        all++;//count seconds
                        //System.out.println(countLeft);
                        countLeft++;
                        //System.out.println(countLeft);
                        
                        if(i<n) {
                            for(int j = 0; j < forward2; j++) {
                                System.out.println("forward: " + forward2);
                                countForward++;
                                all++;
                            }
                            forward2++;
                            i+=1;
                            right +=1;
                            
                            if(i<n) {
                                for(int j =0; j<right;j++) {
                                    System.out.println("right: "+right);
                                    countRight++;
                                    all++;
                                }
                                
                                right +=1;
                                i+=1;
                        
            }
            }
            }
            } 
            }   
            
        }       
    }
    
    //System.out.println("Y"+((countForward )-countBack));
    //in order to find the X co-ordinates we need to minus 
    //the right moves from the left moves
    
    //System.out.println(countLeft);
    //System.out.println("right "+right);
    
    ////in order to find the Y co-ordinates we need to minus 
    //the forward moves from the backward moves
    
    //System.out.println("front " + countForward);
    //System.out.println("back "+ countBack);
    
    System.out.println("after " + (all) + " seconds");
    System.out.println("Coordinate X: " + (countLeft - countRight));
    System.out.println("Coordinate Y: " + (countForward - countBack ));
        
}}
```

When I run the code using small numbers the time seems to be correct, when i run bigger numbers for n the seconds are out of wack. for example when I run the program for n = 10 I get 12 seconds. and I get the following output:

```
Forward 1
left: 1
back: 1
left: 1
forward: 2
forward: 2
right: 2
right: 2
Forward 1
left: 3
left: 3
left: 3
after 12 seconds
Coordinate X: 3
Coordinate Y: 1
```

The X co-ordinate should be 0 and Y = 3;

the algorithm works as follows.

```
forward = 1
left = 1
back = 1
left = 1
forward = 2
right = 2

//end of loop

forward = 1
left = 3
back = 3
left = 1
forward = 4
right = 4

//end of loop
forward = 1
left = 5
back = 5
left = 1
forward = 6
right = 6
```

It creates a box.

Once the code runs for an certain amount of seconds I need to be able to provide the X, Y co-ordinates of where it stops.

*I ended up using the debugger to find the problem and this question has been solved thanks*

Comment: Do you have a debugger?

Comment: It'd be useful to explain your code/algorithm in words rather than say "I have a problem; here's the code". Refer [mcve]

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have made edits to the original post please let me know if this is clearer

Comment: @rghome yes i do i am running this in eclipse

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in Eclipse and step through the code, what do you notice happens differently than what you expect?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will check it out

Comment: @OneCricketeer it seems like my X and Y co-ordinates are working well. I am however having a problem with the seconds. when i put n = 20 i get an output of 43 seconds. I would like if if i put 20 = n then time should equal 20 seconds

Comment: It is working now thanks guys, I found that the for loops inside the conditional statements were running i past n as the check if i<n happens at before the loop. Using the debugger helped me find this. It slipped my mind to use it.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution below as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that my X and Y co-ordinates were correct after running the debugger. I then ran the debugger on the `i` variable. what `i` noticed that when the program was iterating through one of the three for loops it did not check if the `i` variable was greater than `n` until after the loop had completed. this caused the program to exceed `n` and thus more seconds we counted than n. the below code fixed this problem:

```
    public class Steps {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  forward1, left1;
        forward1 = left1 = 1;
        
        int forward2, left2, back, right;
        left2 = back = 0;
        forward2 = right = 1;
        //counts for X coordinate
        int countLeft = 0;//count moves left moves
        int countRight = 0;//count moves right moves
        
        //counts for Y coordinate
        int countForward = 0;//count moves forward moves
        int countBack = 0;//count moves right moves
        
        //n = number of seconds this number will 
        //have 1 added to it
        int n =  43;
        int i = 0;//iterator
        int all = 0;//count total seconds
        
        while(i<n) {//algorithm start
            
            if(i<n) {
                System.out.println("Forward " + forward1);
                left2 += 1;
                all++;
                i++;
                countForward++;
                //System.out.println(countForward);
            
                
                if(i<n) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < left2; j++) {
                        //added if to make sure loop ends 
                        //before i is larger than n
                        if(i<n) {
                            System.out.println("left: " + left2);
                            countLeft++;
                            all++;//count seconds
                            i++;    
                        }
                        
                    }
                    back += 1;
                    //System.out.println(countLeft);
                    
                    
                    if(i<n) {
                        for(int j=0;j<back;j++) {
                            //added if to make sure loop ends 
                            //before i is larger than n
                            if(i<n) {
                                System.out.println("back: " + back);
                                countBack++;
                                all++;
                                i++;
                                //System.out.println(countBack);
                            }
                            
                        }
                        left2 += 1;
                        back += 1;                  
             
                        
                        if(i<n) {
                            System.out.println("left: "+left1);
                            forward2++;
                            all++;//count seconds
                            i++;
                            //System.out.println(countLeft);
                            countLeft++;
                            //System.out.println(countLeft);
                            
                            
                            if(i<n) {
                                for(int j = 0; j < forward2; j++) {
                                    //added if to make sure loop ends 
                                    //before i is larger than n
                                    if(i<n) {
                                        System.out.println("forward: " + forward2);
                                        countForward++;
                                        all++;
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                }
                                forward2++;
                                right +=1;
                                
                                
                                if(i<n) {
                                    for(int j =0; j<right;j++) {
                                        //added if to make sure loop ends 
                                        //before i is larger than n
                                        if(i<n) {
                                            System.out.println("right: "+right);
                                            countRight++;
                                            all++;
                                            i++;
                                        }
                                    }                                   
                                    right +=1;
                            
                }
                }
                }
                } 
                }   
                
            }       
        }
        
        //System.out.println("Y"+((countForward )-countBack));
        //in order to find the X co-ordinates we need to minus 
        //the right moves from the left moves
        
        //System.out.println(countLeft);
        //System.out.println("right "+right);
        
        ////in order to find the Y co-ordinates we need to minus 
        //the forward moves from the backward moves
        
        //System.out.println("front " + countForward);
        //System.out.println("back "+ countBack);
        
        System.out.println("after " + (all+1) + " seconds");
        System.out.println("Coordinate X: " + (countLeft - countRight));
        System.out.println("Coordinate Y: " + (countForward - countBack ));
            
    }}
```

Thanks to those who notified me to use the debugger. Seems like when you are inside the box its difficult to think outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in your code is currently running until `i` is greater than or equal to `n`. Now if you were to change `n` to be the number of second the program should run for then you would need `i` to be the amount of seconds the program has already been running for. Most likely whatever you are running this program on would have taken less than 1850 seconds to complete running, so when you run it for longer you iterate through the while loop many more times, thus changing the result you get.

Comment: I'm having a problem with running it for n. I need a comparator so that the loop can stop

Comment: I would look into the java.time package. You should be able to get the time when the function first starts and then check if the difference between the current time and the starting time is larger than n.